# Results differ between printed output and stored vector in nested for loop. What gives?

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

I believe this may be straightforward, but I have been trying to figure this out for hours. The printed output is how I would like my vector. It is doing exactly what I want.

```
x1<-c(1,2,3,4)
x2<-c(1,0)
len<- length(filename)
output <- vector("numeric", 8)

for (i in x1){
    for(j in x2){
       print(sum(i+j))
       output[i]<- i
    }
}
output
```

But, I am confused as to why I get these two different results:

```
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 2
[1] 4
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 4
> output
[1] 1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0
```

How do I store the `print` results as a vector? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?print`

> print prints its argument and returns it invisibly (via invisible(x)).

We may need to initialize an object (`sum1`) and start concatenating the output from `sum(i + j)`  to the object while updating the output from each iteration back to 'sum1'

```
sum1 <- NULL
 output <- vector("numeric", 8)

 for (i in x1){
     for(j in x2){
      sum1 <- c(sum1, i + j)
  output[i]<- i
  }
 }
```

-output

```
> sum1
[1] 2 1 3 2 4 3 5 4
```

Regarding the difference between the `print` and 'output'.  It is obvious - `print`ing is done on the `sum(i + j)` (`sum` is redundant here as `i + j` does the `sum` as well) where as output is stored with the `i` value alone.  Also the initialization of vector is a numeric vector with value 0 of length 8

```
>  output <- vector("numeric", 8)
> output
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Initialization can also be done as

```
> output <- numeric(8)
```

where as the x1 values are of length 4.  Thus, after the first 4 iteration, there is nothing to fill the 0 value remains as such.

---

In `R`, this can also be done with `outer`

```
> c(t(outer(x1, x2, FUN = `+`)))
[1] 2 1 3 2 4 3 5 4
```

Or with `sapply`

```
> c(sapply(x1, `+`, x2))
[1] 2 1 3 2 4 3 5 4
```